# trouble starting emacs -nw by reading command from a file

Tags: bash, emacs, eval

I have a file containing bash commands, and I read them one by one and call eval to run them.  This was working fine until I try to run "emacs -nw".  I've simplified the problem to the following cases.  Can anyone explain why the emacs commands don't work and how to fix it?  I suspect it has something with quotes and/or the hyphen but can't figure out the problem, and other commands with spaces in them work fine.

Consider these cases:

```
>> cmd="emacs -nw"; echo $cmd; eval $cmd;
```

This works as expected.  Emacs is opened within the current shell.

```
>> cmd="ls /tmp"; echo $cmd; eval $cmd;
```

This works as expected.  I see the contents of /tmp.

```
>> echo "emacs -nw" > /tmp/cmds; cat /tmp/cmds | 
   while read cmd; do echo $cmd; eval $cmd; done
```

This does not work.  I get "emacs: standard input is not a tty", as if I was trying to pipe input to emacs -nw (the way you'd grep and pipe it to less, for example).

```
>> echo "ls /tmp" > /tmp/cmds; cat /tmp/cmds | 
   while read cmd; do echo $cmd; eval $cmd; done
```

This works as expected, so I don't think there's a problem with the quoting/spaces.  That leaves the hyphen, but if I do, say, "ls -alh", that works fine too.

So what's up with the emacs command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pipe into any command, you're replacing its standard input. You're piping into `while ... done`, and `emacs` is part of that command, and so its standard input is the pipe.

I imagine that there would be some clever use of redirection by which you could 'save' and 'restore' stdin, but I haven't come up with it. Or, you could `eval $cmd </dev/tty`.

Comment: Also worth noting that `ls` doesn't have to use stdin so doesn't show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs needs a tty to run in -nw mode your cat | while read loop is using the output of cat as a standard input for all child commands and this is not a tty.  The best thing to do would be to load all of your /tmp/cmd lines into an array of lines and then loop over the array to run each command (but this also might get tricky with quoting issues).